# Ed25519 in simple zero-valued datablocks?

Tags: iota-network

I'm trying to figure out how to send signed messages over the Tangle, in order for the inx-collector to detect them through the specified tag, and generated public key.

Unfortunately, the currently published guide is too complicated for me and as I can see it is based on transactions and not simple published messages. Due to the complexity, I tried to use the ed25519 library in Python, but I can't figure out how to pass both the message AND the signature as part of the data, in order to submit the block.

Any guidance is really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use this library: https://github.com/iotaledger/datapayloads.go

It provides an example you can use as a reference.